# AWS instance was deployed with Whirr. How do I get a key pair of the instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-whirr

I run AWS instance automatically with Apache Whirr.
Then I wanted to connect to this instance with ssh, and I need a key pair to connect.

I went to AWS console and I found, that new key pair was created for this instance.
Since I deployed it automatically with Whirr, there was no possibility to download .pem file.

Is there any way to get the key pair now?
Is there any way to point Whirr on specific key pair to create instance with?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_whirr ubuntu@[instance name]
```

the key pair is actually was generated by me before and stored in ~/.ssh!!